# console messages in FF4 (and a stupid CSS question)

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, console

ok, this code works just fine in Chrome. But, for some reason it does not in FireFox 4 nor IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.testCSS { background-color:#0000AA;color:#BB0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" class="testCSS">Test Div</div>
<script>
    var theRules = new Array();
    if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules) {
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    } else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules) {
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules;
    }
    theRules[0].style["color"] = "#00BB00";
    theRules[0].style["background-color"] = "#BB00BB";
    console.log("background>" + theRules[0].style["background-color"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In FireFox 4 an IE, the line `theRules[0].style["color"] = "#00BB00";` works but the next two do not. It neither changes the background color of the div nor prints out console.log messages (of any sort).  Now, IE does give a message that there is no console.log, so that makes sense. But FireFox gives no error, no warning, no messages. However, it all works perfectly in Chrome. Which gives the console message: `background>rgb(187, 0, 187)` as expected. The line: `theRules[0].style["color"] = "#00BB00";` works in all browsers as expected.

Any ideas why? or how to fix it for FF?

I guess there is two questions here:

1. How to get this working in FF and
2. where did console.log go in FF4?

EDIT: oops, just figured it out. It needs to say "backgroundColor" instead of "background-color".  But, the console.log question still remains, so I'm leaving this question up.

EDIT: Changed title to something more relevant

Pimp Trizkit

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery where this is made to work in all browsers? Chrome uses WebKit layout engine, so this code will probably work in Safari too.

Comment: Probably because I'm still a noob when it comes to JavaScript, and I've managed to do everything I've needed so far without learning about jQuery.  Want to enlighten me?

Comment: `style.backgroundColor` and `style.color` are already cross-compatible. There's no need to add extra overhead or redundancy.

Comment: @Gio I like the way you think, I'm always going for the faster answer ...if it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The more compatible way is to specify the property names in camel case, as you discover:

   ```
   theRules[0].style['backgroundColor']
   ```

   It's so that you can specify the property name in either square bracket notation (above), or dot notation (below):

   ```
   theRules[0].style.backgroundColor
   ```
2. Firefox 4 has a Web Console that you can access in the **Firefox > Web Developer** menu (or **Tools** menu on the menu bar in Mac OS X):

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yes, as you mentioned, I did just figure that out 11 mins before you posted..lol    But, as far as the console.log is concerned, console.log worked just fine in FF3 and Chrome, I kind of assumed it would work in FF4.  BTW, of the two notations you mention, any idea which is the fastest? (I would kindda assume they are identical.. but just in case)

Comment: @Pimp Trizkit: Which is why I said "as you discover" :) Anyway I edited my answer re: Fx 4.

Comment: Any chance of explaining the `window.console` answer a bit more? I'm still lost (and not the OP).

Comment: @Bolt - Bingo thats it, I now see my console messages... I guess they just took them out of the Error console.  THANKS!

Comment: @Crashdown: I edited my answer, you can find the console in Firefox without any extensions. Take a look at the screenshot.